# doing OpenLDAP config changes in RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, ldap

I've been configuring OpenLDAP on RHEL 6 and its seems you have run the following to rebuild the config dirs. I'm ok with that, but my issues is, say I want to change the server passwd, do I have to go through the whole process every time I change the config? Is there a way of changing the slapd config after its been built using the RHEL6 method?

Below is the advice I've [found on the net here](http://www.debianart.org/cchost/people/si0ux/si0ux_-_MoreBlue_Orbit.png).

> This example assumes that the file to convert from the old slapd configuration is located at /etc/openldap/slapd.conf and the new directory for OpenLDAP configuration is located at /etc/openldap/slapd.d/. Remove the contents of the new /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ directory:
>
> `rm -rf /etc/openldap/slapd.d/*`
>
> Run slaptest to check the validity of the configuration file and specify the new configuration directory: slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
>
> Configure permissions on the new directory: chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d
>
> `chmod -R 000 /etc/openldap/slapd.d`
>
> `chmod -R u+rwX /etc/openldap/slapd.d`

To clarify: I'm after help on how to edit the slapd configuration using the newer versions of openldap where the config is held in a schema rather than the original `slapd.conf`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After migration to `slapd.d` configuration directory, `slapd.conf` file is converted to few LDIF files.

For every database that were configured in `slapd.conf` there is now new ldif file in `slapd.d/cn=config/`. Name of that files consist of `olcDatabase={Number}NameOfDatabase.ldif`.

Below there is structure of `slapd.d` in my case (on Debian):

```
slapd.d/
├── cn=config
│   ├── cn=module{0}.ldif
│   ├── cn=schema
│   │   └── cn={0}core.ldif
│   ├── cn=schema.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={1}bdb.ldif
│   └── olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif
└── cn=config.ldif
```

Most important are files `olcDatabase={1}bdb.ldif` and `olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` that includes configuration of two database backends: `bdb` - my primary ldap base and virtual `config` database that is used for dynamic modification of `slapd` config.

Each database have it's own password and root user that are configured in ldif file. Root user and password are defined by these attributes:

```
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,cn=config
olcRootPW:: c2VjcmV0
```

so first method of changing password is just changing value of `olcRootPW`. In that example password is set to word `secret` and is encoded by base64.

We may change `olcRootPW` line to:

```
olcRootPW: plaintextpassword
olcRootPW:: base64decodedtext (in base64 method there is double `:` after attribute name)
olcRootPW: {SSHA}8IAb01fZAtNBH5F0n4x5t2WkmQbhZnWm (SSHA encoded password generated by `slappaswd` command)
```

So if you edit your database file it is done (I'm not sure if `slapd` may be running when you editing ldif files - it's safer to stop it)... but there is another option... ;)

If you have enabled `config` database you could just bind to it using any ldap client (I recommend [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) which is really great ldap client/editor). Of course for binding to that database you must know `olcRootDN` and `olcRootPW` configured for that backend. In that case BaseDN must be set to `cn=config`. After connecting  username and password are normal editable values in `olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config`.