# Connect to LDAP with cn=config in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, ldap

How can I connect with an LDAP-Browser to a Debian Squeeze default openldap-installation? (It uses `cn=config` only).

Answer (score 3):

First you need to set user and password for `config` database, which is configured in file `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif`.

Information about setting password in file you can find in [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16092/doing-openldap-config-changes-in-rhel-6/16102#16102). If you are setting username remember that it must be in format `cn=Manager,cn=config`, where `Manager` word is only thing that you can change.

After that you can bind to that database with data:

- bind DN - `olcRootDN` from config
- bind password - `olcRootPW` from config
- base DN - `cn=config`

When you make your config database running you may configure your primary database by setting `olcRootDN`, `olcRootPW`, `olcSuffix` and ACLs for this database.

As graphical LDAP browser I'm recommending  [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

Comment: You can change the `cn=` as well. I prefer to use `uid=root,cn=config` on my systems.